# DLL not getting copied from wcf service project to wcf server project, when build on Windows server 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, google-api, nuget-package

I have created a google service project in which I have added Google.Apis.Drive.v2 package through NuGet.
Installation of above package resulted in installation of other dependent packages which included following packages:

```
<package id="Google.Apis" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Drive.v2" version="1.9.0.1760" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.28" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Zlib.Portable" version="1.11.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Reference of google service project is added to google server project. 
When I build this project on local machine through Visual Studio 2010, all the google service dll plus the packages dll's gets copied to server folder.

But when i tried to build the solution on Windows server 2012, using msbuild.exe through command prompt, many dll's are not getting copied to server folder. But the solution gets build successfully. These are the dll's which belongs to Microsoft.Net.Http and Zlib.Portable package.

-System.Net.Http.dll

-System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll

-System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll

-System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll

-Zlib.Portable.dll

The way I am making it to work is, I am required to install the following 2 packages in google server project:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.28" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Zlib.Portable" version="1.11.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

But I dont think that's right, as if it works on my local machine, then it should work on server 2012 also.

Can someone please tell me, what's wrong on server 2012?

Comment: wild guess would be that some of the dlls are in GAC on either the server or your local pc?

Comment: The referred dlls are not in GAC, on my local machine as well as windows server 2012.

Comment: What happens if you run msbuild on your local machine?

Comment: Wen I run msbuild on my local machine, none of the google service project dll is getting copied. It throws error like: The primary reference "GoogleService.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework
 assembly "System.Net.Http" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework
. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Comment: But then why build run through Visual Studio, is not giving this warning, and in fact its able to copy all dlls properly.

Comment: I am hardly an MSBuild expert but want to post the command you are using so I can "play" with this.  The issue sounds familiar trying to remember where I have seen this before.

Comment: This is command which I am using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>msbuild "solution path" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"

Comment: Question.  Did you by any chance get a new version of the package from nuget or do a nuget update on the server machine?   Seams the newest release of the package isn't getting all the dependencies.  What version of the dlls are you running?  Probably not related

Comment: I updated all packages of service project. Good thing is some of the dll's are now getting copied in server project. But now the dll which fails to get copied is System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll. I got this link, https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/555 , but my project .net framework is 4.0 and I cant change it to 4.5

Comment: Check my answer library no longer supports 4.0 you wont be getting any new updates.